# React Native Shopping Cart tracking COUNT using AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I am creating a shopping app but i have a problem with my cart. Every time i manage to increase the count of an item, I end up increasing each one of them.

The code is below

Function to get the data retreived from another file

```
const MyCart = ({ navigation }) => {

  const [product, setProduct] = useState();
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(null);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
      getDataFromDB();
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  //get data from local DB by ID
  const getDataFromDB = async () => {
    let items = await AsyncStorage.getItem("cartItems");
    let count = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@count");
    count = parseInt(count);
    items = JSON.parse(items);
    let productData = [];
    let countID = [];
    if (items) {
      Items.forEach((data) => {
        if (items.includes(data.id)) {
          productData.push(data);
          countID.push(data.count);
          return;
        }
      });
      setProduct(productData);
      getTotal(productData);
      getCount(countID);
      setCount(isNaN(count) ? 0 : count);
    } else {
      setProduct(false);
      getTotal(false);
      getCount(false);
    }
  };
```

Increment & Decrement

```
const increment = async (id) => {
    let itemArray = await AsyncStorage.getItem("cartItems");
    itemArray = JSON.parse(itemArray);
    for (let i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
      if (itemArray[i] == id) {
        itemArray[i].count++;
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("@count", (count + 1).toString());
        setCount(itemArray[i].count);
        break;
      }
    }
  };



  const decrement = async (id) => {
    let itemArray = await AsyncStorage.getItem("cartItems");
    itemArray = JSON.parse(itemArray);
    for (let i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
      if (itemArray[i] == id) {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("@count", (count - 1).toString());
        setCount(count - 1);
      }
    }
  };
```

I also have structured my Database.js file like this

```
export const Items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    category: "featured",
    count: 0,
    productName: "1800",
    productPrice: 17.99,
    description: "Tequila",
    isOff: true,
    offPercentage: "10%",
    isAvailable: true,
    productImage: require("../database/images/1800.png"),
    productImageList: [
      require("../database/images/1800.png"),
      require("../database/images/1800-reposado.webp"),
    ],
  },
```

For some reason, the count increases on all of my items. I have 5 days staying up all night trying to solve this problem, please help!

Front end is totally fine, for some reason i just cant increase the count for a specific ID

Answer (score 0):

I've two examples of carts in those projects, take a look. may this help you to fix it.

https://github.com/rodrigodiasf1984/test-cart-next.js-tailwind
https://github.com/rodrigodiasf1984/OnlineShop/tree/master/frontend

Comment: The second one is Private.

The first one, i cant seem to find any cart logic. 
I may be a little bit familiar with TypeScript, but I am using AsyncStorage with ReactNative. 

If you can show me specifically if you have any AsyncStorage method would be great. 

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I've put the second repository public, I don't think Asyncstorage is the best option to handle this, maybe you should try SQLite for example.

Comment: I solved it. AsyncStorage is fine, i just had to create an array for the Count state hook instead of an integer 0 (in my case)